# array values showing undefined in react native expo while working in web

Tags: react-native, expo

The code is working in web version of react native but not in expo The array values are showing unefined but they are working fine in web version.Please tell me what is wrong here

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native"
import React from "react"
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome"
import { faEdit, faMinusSquare } from "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons"

function List({ todoArr, handleModalOpen, removeItem }) {
    console.log(todoArr)
    return (
        <>
            {todoArr.map((item, index) => {
                console.log(index)
                return (
                    <View>

                        <Text key={item} style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>
                        <Text onPress={() => handleModalOpen(index, item)}>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} />
                        </Text>
                        <Text onPress={() => removeItem(index)}>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMinusSquare} />
                        </Text>

                    </View>
                )
            })}
        </>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    item: {

        fontSize: 20
    },
})
export default List
```

Comment: Please share the code where you use the ```List``` component and how you pass in the props to the component.

Comment: @sushrut619 I have

Comment: Is you ```todoArr``` null or empty when you pass it into List component. Would you check by adding a log statement after you call ```Todo()``` in you app component and before render? You might also want to share your ```ToDo``` function code to see if the issue lies in there
Also I think you should be able to edit your question instead of posting edits as answers

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Buttons from './components/Add and Del Btn';
import EditModal from './components/EditModal';
import Heading from './components/Heading';
import Input from './components/Input';
import List from './components/List';
import Todo from './todo';

export default function App() {
  let [indexNo , inpVal,updInpVal ,  todoArr,modalVisible ,setUpdInpVal ,   getInp, add, delAll, removeItem, editItem , handleModalClose , handleModalOpen] = Todo();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <EditModal modalVisible = {modalVisible} updInpVal={updInpVal} setUpdInpVal = {setUpdInpVal} editItem = {editItem} indexNo = {indexNo}/>
      <View>
        <Heading />
        <View>
          <Input getInp={getInp} inpVal={inpVal} />
          <Buttons add={add} delAll={delAll} />
        </View>
        <View>
          <List todoArr={todoArr} handleModalOpen={handleModalOpen} removeItem={removeItem} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View >
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```